# Identify List Template (stp) from SPList Object

Tags: 2013, list, template

I have custom list templates (stp) based on Generic List template. I have created several lists using stp files.

How can I identify from which list template (STP file) the List was created. The properties like `BaseTemplate`, `BaseType`, `TemplateFeatureId` are all returning Generic List template information and not the Custom List Template used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. If you save the stp-file, rename it to cab, opens the cab file and opens the manifest file inside you can see what you can see from the splist. An if it's a generic list, that has added fields. The only way I guess you can do it is to add some kind of information in the schema that will identify the template.

Comment: Thanks, short precise.. Can you give me a few options like what can I add to the Schema, and how programmatically can I identify using SPList object ?

Comment: Not any "nice" solutions. But you could make a hidden view.